# Android: Registering ContextMenu for a Custom ListAdapter

Tags: android, list, contextmenu, adapter

I made a custom list adapter extending the Base adapter. Each item in the list has an imagebutton, 2 textviews and a button. I tried to add the context menu to the list so as to display some options for an item in the list.

```
registerForContextMenu(getListView());
```

I used a MenuInflater object to inflate the context menu xml file. But on clicking the items in the list nothing shows up or the usual highlighting of the item of list on click isn't shown. Is it that the context menu doesn't work for custom list views? Any help would be much appreciated.

Regards,
Primal

Answer (score 9):

Make sure child items of ListView must be Long Clickeable.

It can be done in the xml layout file, for example:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:longClickable="true">

    <!-- Child elements -->

</LinearLayout>
```

Or it can be done in java code:

```
@Override
public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
   CustomView customView = new CustomView();
   customView.setLongClickeable(true);
}
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks, was so helpful for me!

Answer (score 4):

It should work for custom list adapters.  The only thing that comes to mind is that `registerForContextMenu()` needs to be called after `setListAdapter()` (if you're using `ListActivity`).

Comment: For example, see: http://github.com/commonsguy/cw-android/tree/master/Database/Constants/

Comment: I had done the same. But the context menu doesn't pop up on long click. :(

Answer (score 4):

Call registerForContextMenu where appropriate, onCreateView or onCreate.

```
registerForContextMenu(getListView());
```

Implement in your adapter as shown below.

```
 public class CustomeLabelAdpater extends BaseAdapter implements View.OnCreateContextMenuListener{
```

Put this line in your getView method.

```
vi.setOnCreateContextMenuListener(this);

@Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View vi = convertView;
        vi.setOnCreateContextMenuListener(this);
}
```

Put this method as blank in your adapter.

```
 public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu contextMenu, View view, ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo contextMenuInfo) {
         // empty implementation
       }
```

You then override onCreateContextMenu and onContextItemSelected in your fragment or activity.

```
@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu contextMenu, View view,
                                ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo contextMenuInfo) {
    // create context the menu
    Activity.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.context_menu, contextMenu);
}

@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.open:
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similiar problem using a custom adapter while extending ListActivity.

I found that I had to ensure that `setContentView` was being called before `setOnCreateContextMenuListener` in order for these events to register properly.

Example:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    getListView().setOnCreateContextMenuListener(this);

    //  do adapter calls etc here

}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: You always have to call "setContentView" before that for anything.